# how to implement mapbox correctly in xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin, maps, mapbox

i just downloaded the naxam mapbox and am completely lost the github page isn't much of help and there seems to be nothing else can anyone give anything usefull on how to implement the map view in the xamarin.forms app and thanks.

Comment: what specifically are you trying to do that you are having problems with?  Are you getting errors or exceptions?  Just saying "explain how to use X" is an overly broad question and likely to be closed.

Comment: They have a demo app in their repo, just the clone the repo locally and start from there: https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms/tree/master/demo

Comment: yes sorry this is a bit vague but i wanted any guide on how to implement it from scratch the demo is helpfull yet i have to understand everything and look for everything myself wich will take some time... but am already doing so... any other guide or exemples are helpfull .. and thanks for your fast reply guys.

Comment: @amineNoobDeveloper If you want other implementations about map on Xamarin.Forms, this may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

Comment: I'm gonna warn you, the Naxam Mapbox for Forms is broken, i went trough the source code, and some parts broke because the Mapbox SDK has changed since then, the code as not been updated for 9 months and (for what i have searched on LinkedIn), Naxam doesn't exist anymore, so don't bother writing any issues on the GitHub Repo, i have tried the packages and only manage to present the map, adding Markers/Geojson Sources didn't work, i can't tell you exactly what i have done to make it work since the project is for a Internacional Company and the project is secrecy, but i have been in your position

Comment: but here is some help: Naxam binding libraries of Mapbox SDK for Android and iOS still work.

Comment: first off , thanks guys for the replies seriously am lost and ur doing me a huge favour  by giving directions ,
second, from what i understand there's two options
-  either use xamarin.forms implemetation of native map in each platform , sounds like a way to go so i wanna know if there's is any reason to why not, any limitation or concerns if i go this way; 
 - on the other hand i could use naxam mapbox sdk but not for xamarin.forms just the sdk for each platform ?

Comment: ... am currently trying to get a hold of the mapbox demo from the github trying to understand it  should i give it a try or just let go and use sdk for each platform., also seen the mapsui is it worth giving a shot too ?

Comment: @amineNoobDeveloper you should identify the persons here in the comments so that they receive a notification, it happens to me to stumble in this post again while searching for questions in the Mapbox Tag, i will create an anwser for you to clearify all the things up okey? including the maps ui

Comment: See if my anwser is what you needed, if it is, don't forget to upvote and mark it as the anwser (and i'm sorry that i couldn't post any more relevant code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Anwser:**

The *Naxam.Mapbox for Xamarin.Forms* Nuget Package, and all the associated Forms ones, have not been update since **Sep 12, 2018**, and the *Mapbox SDK*'s for *Android/iOS* have changed since then, i tried this package and it's a bit clunky, i have manage to display the map, but inserting Geojson Sources/ Markers is not a pleasant experience.

**EDIT 2019/10/13**

Last month, Naxam updated their nuggets to the latest Mapbox version for .Forms, Android and iOS

---

**Long Anwser:**

If you really want to use **Mapbox** in your Xamarin Projects, the Naxam Binding Libraries for [Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.Mapbox.Droid/) and [iOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.Mapbox.iOS/) are still working today (**18/06/2019**), So one way to have it working for a Xamarin Forms Project is to implement both sdk's in their respective project, and use them in a *Custom View Renderer* (and be carefull, because those projects still need other Nuget Packages to work, and they don't warn you when you install them, be sure see the dependecies in the links i gave above).

Other way to have a map in your project is by using [MapsUi](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui) (Remember that MapsUi is **TileBased** and Mapbox is **VectorBased**, so you might see less fluidity while using MapsUi). i will leave here some relevant code for the custom render in iOS for the implementation of MapsUi to get started:

***MapViewRenderer.cs***

```
public class MapViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MapsUIView, Mapsui.UI.iOS.MapControl>
{
    Mapsui.UI.iOS.MapControl mapNativeControl;
    MapsUIView mapViewControl;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MapsUIView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (mapViewControl == null && e.NewElement != null)
            mapViewControl = e.NewElement;

        if (mapNativeControl == null && mapViewControl != null)
        {
            var rectangle = mapViewControl.Bounds;
            var rect = new CGRect(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);

            mapNativeControl = new Mapsui.UI.iOS.MapControl(rect)
            {
                Map = mapViewControl.NativeMap,
                Frame = rect
            };

            SetNativeControl(mapNativeControl);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the base on how to implement the MapView in a Custom View Render in iOS, similiar code is needed for Android, and of course, the Custom Renderer itself, wich there is tons of tutorials on how to do it, like this ones: [Source 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) [Source 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ux09gAB13kQ)

Comment: the most complete answer i've seen xD...thanks a lot.

Comment: @amineNoobDeveloper it's not even that completed :( i could give you more sample code if i could, but i'm glad i could help

Comment: noo thiis is actualy pretty helpfull am really thankfull to you , i have to make my own custom rendrer to show mapbox maps, if the results are not satisfyin i'll try mapsui thanks for the two links for custom renderer i was already reading the xamarin forms documentation, but the vid is a great add on .... from here i should be able to make what am aiming for in no time...  reaalyy REALLYY THANK YOU A LOT.

Comment: but one more question, about mapbox, is it still free or is it no longer that way, cuz am seeing pricing page i don't quite understant it ... sorry for the random question but if you could just answer this one and thanks again for your time .

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/ here you can see you have free tiers for the Mapbox Mobile SDK's, wich is when you have less than 25,000 active users, they state: "Only pay for what you use. Don’t get stalled by contracts, capacity planning, or price modeling.", so if you expect your app to grow beyond those numbers, you will have to pay

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais where I can find pricing for MapsUI?

Comment: @YauhenSampir MapsUi is OpenSource, so there's no pricing (from what i know of)

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais ahhh sorryy again am such a pain in the ass xD ... the mapbox navigation sdk.... should i do the same for it to get it workig...custom renderer , and is the binding lib is still working? or should i just give up on mapbox and go back to google maps xD

Comment: the mapbox navigation is a diferent sdk? or just a plugin?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais it's a diffrent sdk and there is a binding library for xamarin in github...i have no idea if i should give it a shot or it's just gonna waste my time.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais euuuhhh i just checked github and mapbox website... there is two navigation SDKs , a NAVIGATION SDK ,and NAVIGATIONUI SDK.... the saad part is , there is no longer NAVIGATION SDK binding library on github... there still only the navigationui binding library, ... wich basically means in summary, either mapbox does something about it , or u can't use it in xamarin;... going back to google maps... i guess.

Comment: @amineNoobDev i guess, i have never really used the navigation from mapbox

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais do you have any idea if i make the binding libraries myself how much of work should be done , like is it possible to do when i have really never done that before ?

Comment: @amineNoobDev It's alot of work, i'm not gonna lie, but everyone can do it if they learn how to do it

Comment: @amineNoobDev https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/location-component/ is this enough for what you are looking for?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais no it's not wat i want actually i want a map with markers, and navigation, plus of course the location component wich is  the least of my problems now xD ... so yeah i have to : 1) either ditch mapbox , 2) or ditch xamarin , 3) or make binding lib myself .... gotta chose an option to go with now xD ... gotta go out of my confort zone in any of these cases , xD ahahahhaahah
thank youu again thoo you were very helpfull thanks a lot.